# Install zeroshell from usb error "Waiting for root device /dev/sr0"

Tags: boot, usb

I'm using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.8 to burn Zeroshell to an usb disk and boot from this usb,

I see this error when I boot from this usb. How do I resolve this error?

Here is the screen boot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can resolve by install zeroshell from zeroshell command line,

In my case:
 Install zeroshell to VirtualBox using ISO file,
 Open virtual machine,
 Plug usb,
 Comback to virtual machine, press A and select USB to install,

Then i can boot from my usb with zeroshell

Answer (score 0):

This problem cause you tried install CD ISO Image from USB Flash disk. You need just download IMG archive from [ZeroShell downloads page](http://www.zeroshell.org/download/#), and then write it on Flash Disk by [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) or other IMG burner.